# What's the correct way to enable clean urls when the site is hosted in a sub directory?

Tags: 7, uri

Until recently, I've never used Drupal in a subfolder before, and having followed the directions in the .htaccess file as well as [this page](https://drupal.org/node/15365), I'm unable to get it working.

Drupal projects will be stored in the following structure:

- localhost/drupal/project1
- localhost/drupal/project2
- localhost/drupal/project10

Here is where I am:

1. Per the .htaccess file I uncommented the rewrite rule for subdirectories so that it reads `RewriteBase /drupal/project1`
2. Per the link above I changed the httpd.conf file to read AllowOverride All so .htaccess overrides would work.

Yes, the rewrite module is installed and working. Yes, I've restarted Apache several times and cleared Drupal cache. I've even tried different variations of the rewrite base.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Did you ran this command "a2enmod rewrite"?

Comment: yes, rewrite is enabled (This is CentOS so, the LoadModule line for rewrite in uncommented and working)

Comment: I have at least a dozen sites that place the Drupal root in a subfolder of the web root. In my experience, there is nothing special about it. Clean URLs are enabled automatically after a clean install, provided Apache mod rewrite is enabled. I've never had to do anything special, (such as editing the default `.htaccess` that is installed as part of a clean install). This is whether the Drupal root is in a subfolder of the web root, or not. Have you tried to install *without* changing the default `.htaccess?

Comment: Do clean URLs work on this server in the root directory? @FreeRadical You also need `Options Indexes` and `AllowOverride All` in the Apache config for the Drupal DOCROOT for clean URLs to work.  I literally just had this problem on a site an hour ago.

Comment: Locally, I only work with sub folders. The times I had problems with getting clean URL's working correctly, it was the rewritebase setting (part of the mod rewrite class of settings) that was not set correctly.